# Masonry with Drupal Views infinite scroll

Tags: jquery, drupal, jquery-masonry, infinite-scroll, drupal-8

I have some troubles with getting Masonry to work with an infinite scroll page in Drupal 8.

When it loads in the new items with ajax masonry does not run on the new items, and therefore not displaying them correctly.

I have spent hours trying to get this to work but nothing seems to get it to reload. I have also tried appended, but that doesn't seem to do the trick either.

```
  var $grid = $('.view-id-articles .view-content');
  $grid.imagesLoaded( function(){
    $grid.masonry({
      itemSelector: '.views-row',
      columnWidth: '.grid-sizer',
      percentPosition: true,
      gutter: 12
    });

    $(document).on('infiniteScrollComplete', function() {
      var $items = $('.view-id-articles .view-content .views-row');
      console.log('infiniteScrollComplete');
      console.log($items); // refresh masonry

      $grid.masonry({
        itemSelector: '.views-row',
        columnWidth: '.grid-sizer',
        percentPosition: true,
        gutter: 12
      });
      $grid.masonry('reloadItems');
      $grid.masonry('layout');

    });

  });
```

Comment: Have you already checked out the example of adding items? There are two methods `appended` ("Layout new items to the end of layout") and `reload` ("will layout all the item elements in the container, which is useful for prepending or inserting.")  **[Masonry Demos - Adding items](http://desandro.github.io/masonry/demos/adding-items.html)** . Maybe you have to use them after you loaded the new elements into the DOM

Comment: Yes I have tried them. I am running v3 though, so not the one you were linking to.